# EventEmitter do not emit value

Tags: angular

Do not log nothing in parent component.
[image: Do not log nothing in parent component]

I want to emit from child component to parent component using @Output() and EventEmitter(). In my child component function it's getting triggered on click and emit the value but parent component do not recieve any value.

I tryed to debug, stacktrace and console.log in parent component but do not get triggered

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxhn4k)**

**Child Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() valueChanges: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeRegisterForm();
  }

  public initializeRegisterForm(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [''],
      password: [''],
      confirmPassword: [''],
      email: [''],
      confirmEmail: [''],
    })
  }

  public submitRegisterForm(): void {
    // delete this.registerForm.value['confirmPassword'];
    // delete this.registerForm.value['confirmEmail'];
    this.valueChanges.emit('test');
  }
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-user',
  templateUrl: './auth-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-user.component.css']
})
export class AuthUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // Leave it any for now create model later
  public registerUser(event): void {
    console.log('output not working?')
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Parent component HTML:

```
<app-register (valueChanges)="registerUser($event)"></app-register>
```

When user submit form submitRegisterForm() function it's invoked and `valueChanges` it's triggered but I do not receive the data in the parent component

Comment: Where is your `Parent component HTML` ?

Comment: a stackblitz will make it easier for us to help

Comment: Seems all is well implemented, could u create a stackblitz ?

Comment: Sorry here u go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxhn4k

Comment: Your stackblitz is working fine. I don't see any issue there.

Comment: Provide photo as well. Can't see any logs in my parent component and that makes me crazy.

Comment: Please show your HTML from where `submitRegisterForm()` is called

Comment: Did you try a different browser?

Comment: I just updated to angular 7.1.4 from 6.2.5 and now is working but still don't make sense to me